# How do I troubleshoot my central A/C?

Tags: hvac, cooling, air-quality

It's 79 outside right now.
It's been running for hours and it's remaining 79 inside.

I'm in a brand new 2 story home in Monroe, OH.

It has rained a lot recently but I just feel like it should be cooler...

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

It's roughly 77F outside and humidity is 76% outside.  It's now 80F in my house and the thermostat is set at 70F.

Still no ideas if this sounds right?

Comment: Central A/C or window unit? How long have you had it? Has it worked properly in the past? What model thermostat do you use? etc ....

Comment: May be obvious, but what's the temperature you've set your thermostat at?

Comment: It's central AC.  This is a new construction, 2360sq ft 2 story with finished basement so vents running there too.  We have a Nest 2nd gen thermostat.  I've checked outside and the AC is running...  The thermostat is set at between 69 and 71 but obviously it never reaches that

Comment: Is cool air blowing from your vents?

Comment: I mean... It's semi-cool I suppose... Definitely cooler than the air in the room...

Comment: It sounds like just the fan is running.

Comment: I'm thinking I've pretty much confirmed it's just not working... the power is running to it, fan outside is on in the unit, but no cool air is coming through... just outside temperature air...